# Error on SQL insert statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I exported a recordset from one database into a csv file, and when I try to import it into another using mysql workbench I keep this this error message:

```
Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'Lord it Over', 'Ben', '1993-03-01', 'TRC', NULL, 1983, '1999-09-01', 'NULL', '' at line 1



INSERT INTO `TRC`.`horse` 
(`horse_id`, `registered_name`, `stable_name`, `arrival_date`, `last_known_location`, `is_ex_racer`, `birth_year`, `death_date`, `horse_comments`, `sex`, `referral_date`, `horse_height`, `arrival_weight`, `passport_no`, `microchip_no`, `is_on_waiting_list`) VALUES 
(, 'Lord it Over', 'Ben', '1993-03-01', 'TRC', NULL, 1983, '1999-09-01', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', NULL, NULL, 'NULL', 'NULL', 0)



SQL script execution finished: statements: 29 succeeded, 1 failed



Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch
```

Any help would be appreciated as their appears to be no errors as far as I can see.

Comment: Is the inserted value for horse_id an empty string '' or NULL?

Comment: empty string, I can change it to null if needed though

Answer (score 1):

It's becaose of

- `VALUES` starts with a comma.
- You have missed `horse_id`. If it's Identity Column Then Remove `horse_Id`

Try like this (If horse_Id is identity)

```
INSERT INTO `TRC`.`horse` 
(`registered_name`, `stable_name`, `arrival_date`, `last_known_location`, `is_ex_racer`, `birth_year`, `death_date`, `horse_comments`, `sex`, `referral_date`, `horse_height`, `arrival_weight`, `passport_no`, `microchip_no`, `is_on_waiting_list`) VALUES 
('Lord it Over', 'Ben', '1993-03-01', 'TRC', NULL, 1983, '1999-09-01', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', NULL, NULL, 'NULL', 'NULL', 0)
```

Or (If `Horse_id` simple int then try this)

```
 INSERT INTO `TRC`.`horse` 
    (`horse_id`, `registered_name`, `stable_name`, `arrival_date`, `last_known_location`, `is_ex_racer`, `birth_year`, `death_date`, `horse_comments`, `sex`, `referral_date`, `horse_height`, `arrival_weight`, `passport_no`, `microchip_no`, `is_on_waiting_list`) VALUES 
    ('1','Lord it Over', 'Ben', '1993-03-01', 'TRC', NULL, 1983, '1999-09-01', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', NULL, NULL, 'NULL', 'NULL', 0)
     ^^^^  -- Here Horse_Id missing
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see what you guys are saying about eliminating the horse_id field from the statement, but I'm trying to import the data set into the inserts section of the model, so I can create the tables and data together, but there doesn't seem to be a way to remove the primary key field this way?

Answer (score 0):

Your `VALUES` starts with a comma for some reason

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you missing your "horse_id" value.
If that field was intended to be the Identity field, then you shouldn't mention that field on Insert Statement right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want MySQL to generate an auto_increment ID for the `horse_id` field, you should either leave it out of the `INSERT` statement entirely, or specify `NULL` for the value in the `VALUES` list. You can't just leave that value empty in the list.